# bash online - how to exit from flow -ing output

Tags: linux, bash, unix

eg: tail -f /var/log/messages | head -3

i want to exit the command, and first 3 result to be displayed in the console at the same time.
PS: not looking options tail  /var/log/messages | head -3

Comment: If you want the command to exit and just print the first 3 lines then remove the `-f` flag.

Comment: yes..i am aware of that command, but like i said i am looking for different options... like terminate after head -3

Comment: can EXIT be used in above scenerio

Comment: The reason the command does not end is because tail -f leaves its output stream open.  So your question is ill-formed, kind of.  So no, tail has no other options for this.  You  will have to create an asynchronous trap - a separate piece of code that sleeps for one second then kills the process doing the tail command.  Dropping the -f is infinitely easier.

Comment: thank Jim... and i agree dropping -f will solve the issue. tail is just an example. actually I have a F5 command. ie iqdump <ip address>

Comment: this iqdump is a flowing command, and i want just the head -3 and terminate..how can i do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do

`head -3 <(tail -f /var/log/messages)`

this way it won't block.

Comment: kudos Bro.. it worked like a charm..

Comment: there was a good thread about this here, but I cannot find it at the moment.. it's basically a fault of how bash handles pipes, not recognising that `head` finished. but it works this way...

Answer (score 0):

Karoly's answer is very good, but there really is no option to tail to do this.

Another really cumbersome way, if process substitution won't work for you is to use fifos.

```
mkfifo myfifo
somecommand  > myfifo &
my_pid="$!" # pid of somecommand
head -3 myfifo > out.file & 
sleep 1
kill $my_pid 
wait # wait for head to quit.
```

Comment: well, that's a bit brittle, you're assuming the feeding process will produce enough content in a second... which is not always the case.

Comment: IT is the same idea as the "timeout" for a read statement in bash.  I agree it is not very useful. But I mentioned a trap earlier, so this is one of several possibilities.